# Getting error in populating the javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My simple javascript code is following. In this i am getting error "can not set property of undefined" in populating the location arrary.

```
var locations = [];
for (var i=0;i<center_add.length;i++)
{
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  // center_add[i].toString();
  // alert(center_add[i].toString());
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': center_add[i].toString()}, function(results, status) {
      locations[i]=[];
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      locations[i][0] = center_add[i].toString();
      // Uncought TypeError="Can not set property '0' of undefined.
      locations[i][1]= results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      locations[i][2]= results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: check `typeof == 'undefined'` before accessing the array elements

Comment: You are missing `locations[i] = [];`

Comment: @IgorJerosimić still showing the same error.....

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error, because it doesn't seem to be likely? Anyway, try to find a way to reproduce the error in an environment we can check (JsFiddle, live site, etc) so we can be of more assistance.

Comment: @Tibos get solved. i was missing s in locations.....thanks